# Elimination problem with polynomial equations involving multiple variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Hi guys I am very stuck with this problem. I am trying to eliminate 2 out of the three variables it does not matter which one remains, I personally tried keep x and eliminate the others. My question also a general way to eliminate variables in such equations.

$$A= (N)z(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5+y(2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5))$$
$$B=(N)zy((x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5))$$
$$1=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+y(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5))$$

Here A, B and N are constants. I know via math software that the ideal defined by those equations is of degree 7.

What I have tried is using resultants to eliminate first z and then y. SO far unsuccessfully. I would appreciate some fresh ideas and possible approaches.

Comment: Is the repeated $x^3$ in the third equation is not a typo?

Comment: It was!!Thank you I fixed it.

Comment: there is another one in the same equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce vectors
${\bf x} = (x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5)$,
${\bf a} = (2,3,4,5)$ and
${\bf b} = (1,1,1,1)$
rewrite the equations compactly using dot products of these vectors
$$A=N z(x +{\bf a}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y))$$
$$B=Nzy {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}$$
$$1=1+x+ {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y)$$

Clearly 
$$x=-{\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y)
%=-{\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}\left(1+\frac{B}{Nz {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}}\right)
$$
and
$$z=\frac{B}{Ny {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}}$$

from the other side
 $$z=\frac{A}{N (x +{\bf a}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y))}
=\frac{A}{N (-{\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y) +{\bf a}\cdot{\bf x}(1+y))}
=\frac{A}{N ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}(1+y)}
$$
Thus
$$\frac{A}{ ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}(1+y)}=\frac{B}{y {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}}$$
$$Ay {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}=B ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}(1+y)$$
$$(A {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}-B ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x})y=B ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}$$
$$y=\frac{B ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}}{
((A+B) {\bf b}-B {\bf a})\cdot{\bf x}}$$
substitute into $x$ and $z$

$$x
=-{\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}\left(1+\frac{B ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}}{
((A+B) {\bf b}-B {\bf a})\cdot{\bf x}}\right)
$$
and
$$z=\frac{1}{N {\bf b}\cdot{\bf x}}
\frac{((A+B) {\bf b}-B {\bf a})\cdot{\bf x}}
{ ({\bf a}-{\bf b})\cdot{\bf x}}
$$